# More than one letter in an xbindkeys binding

Tags: xbindkeys

Is there a way to configure a shortcut in `xbindkeys` that utilises multiple letters? e.g., I'd like to have `alt + a + e` bound to a command

I've already tried using `xbindskeys -k` but no luck :( Is it possible? Is there an alternative program otherwise?

Comment: No, and I would claim logic dictates this is not possible as it would introduce conflicts: what would a keybinding alt + a do in your scenario?  The keys pressed before a character need to be actual modifiers (so control, shift, alt, win key). Those you can combine with more than one.

Comment: @Rinzwind I'm not sure I follow - this is a standard practice on most OS. `alt + a` would either do nothing, or execute the command bound to `alt + a`, as it does not include the final `+ e` specified in the shortcut. Meanwhile, if `alt + a` and `alt + a + e` were both defined, I'd expect it easily differentiate the two depending on `keyup` and `keydown` for the respective letters - the algorithm isn't complicated! Consider on Ubuntu, pressing `super` vs `super + a` as a great example of how this is very possible